# How do I go about generating log file for my program

Tags: java, logging

I have a sample program which sends http post request and gets a response from server. While in the process of running the program, I am reading data from a file(txt/xml/DB) and executing the http request and the relevant response will be written back to file respectively.

Based on the above functionality, I have planned for a log file which writes exceptions, errors(paths), methods executed, classes executed and a time stamp.

Please tell me any logging programs in java, may be log4j is relevant for this kind of scenario?

Comment: yes log4j is good choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

log4j is more or less the defacto for logging and allows logging to files, db, jms etc. 
There are many resources on the net, a simple guide to configure it using a property file and a sample program to initialize it and start logging can be found here: http://www.javabeat.net/baisc-steps-to-configure-log4j-using-xml-and-properties-file/

You can read more about various logging levels and possibilities of logging in multiple files (i.e. Access logs in one, Errors in another etc)

Comment: After few hours of posting this question, I did some research and found out sfl4j with logback is better than log4j. However, my question is how do figure which class and method got executed using slf4j ? Is it possible to print the class name and method names which got executed using sfl4j?

Comment: Not well versed with sfl4j, but log4j2 is out and takes the best of both. Logging class name as well as method name is possible in log4j.http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html     however note that the doc warns that it can slow down things. Another option is to explicitly log the method name yourself in the log comment